# ButtonLook property not in angular kendobutton

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I am having an issue setting the [look] property in kendobutton. I receive an error stating that look is not a property of button. What should I check to make this work for me?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @MickaëlB is right but this usually happens when you dont import that module or add to ngModule's imports.

Answer (score 0):

[look] is not an html attribute of button.

You can try to use [attr.look] to set custom attributes in an angular template.
E.g.:  Click me!

You can find more info here:
https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding